# The problem is with the strings in the class that I transmit over the socket

Tags: c++

```
class JoinPlayerPacket {
public:
    PacketType type;
    const char* playerId; // turns into incomprehensible characters after transmission over a socket
};

/////////////////////////SERVER////////////////////////////

JoinPlayerPacket packet;
packet.playerId = "maxrskiy";
send(sock, (char*)packet, sizeof(packet), 0);

/////////////////////////CLIENT////////////////////////////

LeavePlayerPacket buf;
int bytesReceived = recv(sock, (char*)&buf, 4096, 0);
cout << buf.playerId << endl; // displays garbled characters
```

I ran into a problem when I tried to pass a class in which there is a variable with a string on a socket, the string on the side of which I pass the class was deformed, that is, it turned into incomprehensible characters. How can you avoid this? I am using a TCP socket.

Comment: Sending pointers via socket is not a good idea. Instead of that, send the string data itself.

Comment: Memory and memory maps and where pointers are pointing is local to each *process*. Even if two processes are running the same program, their memory maps (and their pointers) will be different. Now think about what happens when you pass a pointer (which is what you're doing) between two different processes.

Comment: suppose I want to send you a letter. It is not sufficient I tell you that the letter is in the 3rd drawer of my locker. You open the 3rd drawer of your locker and the letter is not there :(. Instead I have to send you the letter.

Comment: Can you please give an example of how to send me the class correctly?

Comment: You might want to do some search into *serialization*.

Comment: How can this be done?

Comment: FYI: [Serialization and Unserialization](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization) (from the C++ FAQ)

Comment: `buf` is of type `JoinPlayerPacket` which contains two members: `PacketType type;` and `const char* playerId;`. Whatever the first is, the second is a pointer to one or more `char`s. Sending the `buf` will just send the address of these `char`s which is useless in any other than the sending process. You have to write a function which serializes (aka. encodes) the contents of `buf` into a sequence of bytes which can be consumed (with sense) on the receivers side. (Read again the story with the letter above. Maybe, you understand now that it's the analogy to what you try to do...)

Comment: Related: [Boost.Serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Comment: The problem is with the *pointers* you are sending in this class. They certainly aren't going to point to the same thing at the peer.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, you are sending internal pointer to your char array, not the array itself. Your class does not contain the array but pointer to it.
The easiest and common (especially in C) method is using in-place arrays, eg:

```
#include <array>

class JoinPlayerPacket {
public:
    PacketType type;
    std::array<char, 100> playerId;
};

JoinPlayerPacket packet;
packet.playerId = {"maxrskiy"};
send(sock, (char*)&packet, sizeof(packet), 0);
```

In this example `std::array` is just assignable wrapper for arrays. This way you can assign it easily. You can also use raw array `char playerId[100]` but then you will have to assign each character separately. You can use `std::copy` or similar function to copy characters there.

```
#include <string>

class JoinPlayerPacket {
public:
    PacketType type;
    char playerId[100] = {};  // Either zero initialize it here
};

JoinPlayerPacket packet{};  // Or here
const std::string name = "maxrskiy";
std::copy(name.cbegin(), name.cend(), packet.playerId);
packet.playerId[name.length()] = '\0';  // Or at least add trailing zero after your string
send(sock, (char*)&packet, sizeof(packet), 0);
```

The whole point of it is to have the array inside your class, not allocated separately. In both cases you are placing 100 character array inside your class and that's what you will send. Obviously the size is constant so you will always send some garbage or zeros at the end of the string.

In the second solution you have to watch out for the content of the array. You only copy characters of your text and not trailing zero which indicates the end of the string. It means that if there was `1234567890`, then you will end up with `maxrskiy90`. Either you have to zero initialize it in the class constructor (I used inline initialization from C++11), or zero initialize it on creation, or simply add trailing zero after your last character. In both cases you also have to secure it from overflowing, you only have 99 characters and trailing zero!

More advanced method is to serialize it - send number of characters and then all of the characters. This way you can make it any length you want but you will have to create binary message before sending and then properly desalinize it back to your structure after receiving.

Comment: c++ prevents me from converting JoinPlayerPacket to char*

Comment: on the line where std::copy occurs, it says the class JoinClassPlayer does not contain a variable playerId

Comment: @maxrskiy It complained about ```playerID``` which I misspelled while adding ```std::copy```. The variable is ```playerId```. Second issue was in your code from the start, I did not actually look at it. Socket expects pointer to the buffer and you were casting your object to pointer type instead of casting pointer to object to a different type of pointer. Using ```&packet``` you are taking the address of ```packet``` which is of type ```JoinPlayerPacket*``` and now you can cast it to ```char*```.